# Show that an ideal $I\le k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is radical if $\langle LT(A)\rangle$ is

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field, let $A$ be an ideal of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and let $>$ be a monomial order. I'm asked to show that $A$ is radical if $\langle LT(A)\rangle$ is radical.

So, suppose $\langle LT(A)\rangle$ is radical, and $y^n\in A$. We want to show that $y\in A$. We can choose a Grobner basis for $A$, i.e. $A=\langle y_1,\ldots,y_k\rangle$ and $\langle LT(A)\rangle=\langle LT(y_1),\ldots,LT(y_k)\rangle$. How can we proceed from here?

Comment: Hint: You may then want to use the generalized division algorithm with your Grobner basis and get remainder $r$. Can you show that $LT(r)\in \langle LT(A) \rangle$ and hence must be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You may then want to use the generalized division algorithm with your Grobner basis and get remainder r. Can you show that LT(r)∈⟨LT(A)⟩ and hence must be 0?